# Fedora not finding network card after installing updates

Tags: networking, fedora

I had Fedora 11 on a machine I built for quite a while. Then yesterday I downloaded a bunch of updates, then my network card quit working. I couldn't resolve the problem so I did a fresh install of Fedora 12 and I'm still having the same problem. It's not seeing my network card. I don't know exactly what the card is -- it's attached to the motherboard. 
Is there anything I can do or is it likely that it's just not supported anymore in which case it's time to start upgrading hardware???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not finding, do you mean that `lspci` does not find anything? My machine has two network cards:

```
$ lspci | grep -i eth
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
05:04.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
$
```

If this is the case you probably can find more details in the kernel log, see `/var/log/messages` or run `dmesg`.

Maybe you can also try `system-config-network`. Is your card missing from there?

Or do you mean that maybe the card is there, but the network initialisation is not working at startup? If so try `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0`.

Comment: It's simply not found anywhere. 

lspci | grep -i eth returns nothing ;(

Comment: Do you have old versions of/content from /var/log/messages from before your upgrade? You could try to compare. Another option is to try an older kernel version, it might be that your newer kernel does not detect it properly.

Comment: I keep trying to view the logs but it keeps freezing up before I get there. Argh. I may try downgrading the kernel -- assuming I can figure out how. Thanks!

Comment: You do not necessarily have to downgrade the kernel, you could try to just boot from an older live CD.